# Specified covariance matrix in lmer in R for penalized splines

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, nlme

I have been trying to fit a penalized spline regression model in R using the connection between penalized splines and linear mixed models. While I am quite familiar with the R function `lme`, using its competitor `lmer` presents some difficulties. Here is a toy example I would like to generalize to `lmer`:

```
require(nlme)

grid <- seq(0, 1, len = 100)
y <- rep(0, length(grid))
for(i in 1:length(grid)){
  y[i] <- sin(3*pi*grid[i])  + rnorm(1, 0, 1)
}
X <- cbind(rep(1, length(grid)), grid, grid^2, grid^3)
knots <- seq(0.01, 0.99, len = 100)
Z <- outer(grid, knots, "-")
Z <- Z*(Z>0)
Z <- Z^3
data.mixed <- data.frame(X, Z)
data.mixed$all <- rep(1 ,nrow(data.mixed))
fit.mixed <- lme(y~ X-1, random = list( all  = pdIdent(~Z-1) ), data = data.mixed )
curve(sin(3*pi*x), 0, 1, lwd = 2, ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5))
beta.hat <- fit.mixed$coefficients$fixed
u.hat <- unlist(fit.mixed$coefficients$random)
f.hat <- X%*%beta.hat + Z%*%u.hat
lines(grid, f.hat, lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

The tricky part is pdIdent function which specifies that while we have several random effects their covariance structure is a multiple of the identity matrix; `lme` then estimates this scalar multiple.

If anyone is familiar with `lmer`, I would greatly appreciate some hints on how to accomplish this with that function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Generally, the covariance structure is not as flexible in `lmer` than `lme`; although I generally use `lmer` nowadays, for things like this I definitely go back to `lme`.  Is there a particular reason you want to make the switch?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for answering. The reason is that many packages are extensions of lmer and so it's important for my work to know how to at least specify the penalized spline model in that syntax.

Comment: @BenBolker's probably your best bet -- good luck!

Comment: If you have the time @BenBolker perhaps you can take a look. As far as I know this is a question by many.

Comment: just so you know, I believe the @ only notifies users if they've already commented on the post, but I know Ben follows the lme4 and nlme tags, so hopefully he'll see it. Or try contacting him directly via his contact information as maintainer of the package.

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86961/3601, and numerous other questions there for general comments on covariance structures in `nlme` and `lme4`.